# how can I remove/delete data from server node.js using interval time/ settimeout?

Tags: node.js

hi I'm trying create chat using node.js
I see example in http://chat.nodejs.org/
I have tried it and it works but how can I remove/delete data from server using interval time like in javascript  without have to restart node.js/ terminal prompt?....
example:
time:
17:14
17:12
16:13
15:11
14:17

```
function del(){
if(time<timenow-1000){delete time;}}

setInterval("del()",10000);
```

I want to delete data less than two hours ago every one hours using interval time...thanks

Comment: `setInterval` is the correct way to run code at intervals, but you're already using it. So what's the question?

Comment: my questi I can't delete it.how to delete data on server?if you try chat app http://chat.nodejs.org if you send data,data will push in server..ok I will explain details from beginning..first I will run node.js using command prompt(win)..I call it using node server.js command..then I open my browser http:\\localhost:8001 it will open html form for chating..I submit form and data will pushed into server,I close mybrowser and I open new another browser and data still exist..although I close my browser data in server will not be removed/deleted until I close comand prompt window..how to delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would highly recommend against using the `setInterval` overload you are using that takes an `eval` string. Instead, always use the version that takes a callback. For example:

```
setInterval(1000, function () {
  // do something
});
```

Take a look at the source and you will see that messages are stored in the `messages` array:
https://github.com/ry/node_chat/blob/master/server.js

Your function just needs to inspect this array and remove messages whose timestamp is older than your desired date. For example:

```
setInterval(1000, function () {
  while (messages.length && messages[0].timestamp < someTime) {
    messages.shift();
  }
});
```

This will keep removing the oldest message while it is older than `someTime`, which is a time you will need to specify.

Comment: yes you are right... it does work now...I forgot all messages saved in server.js.....thank you very much...

Comment: @ankifreeze If this is right, would you mind accepting the response as the correct answer? That will resolve this question.

Comment: hi sorry for late i forgot three years ago...i have accepted yours as correct answer